# Execute System Commands in Java on Mac

Tags: java, macos, terminal, command

I want to be able to make run a system command on Mac OSX from within Java. My code looks like this:

```
public void checkDisks() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("df -h");
    int exitValue = p.waitFor();
    System.out.println("Process exitValue:" + exitValue);


    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                                 p.getInputStream()));
    String line = reader.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        line = reader.readLine();
    }
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

This always returns null and an exitValue of 0. Never done this before in Java so any thoughts or suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: 0 indicates normal execution of the command "df -h", but why are you trying to read the InputStream from p ? you may want to read from a file instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is almost OK, you just misplaced the println

```
public void checkDisks() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("df -h");
    int exitValue = p.waitFor();
    System.out.println("Process exitValue:" + exitValue);


    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                                 p.getInputStream()));
    String line = reader.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        line = reader.readLine();
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

I believe it's what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: That'll do for testing purposes. When using in production, I'd advise using StringBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
public void checkDisks() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"df","-h"});
    int exitValue = p.waitFor();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                                 p.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line=reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
    }
    System.out.println("Process exitValue:" + exitValue);
}
```